# php mixing foreach and for return duplicate

Tags: php

Here is my **[code](https://ideone.com/Ad9gq1)** and you can run this with `html` output with **[this](http://www.runphponline.com/)**. i have an array (multiple select option) and i want to add `selected="selected"` to those equal with `$districts` array. so i write a `foreach` for array to string (select options) then a for loop for explode `$districts`

```
foreach ($readJson as $key => $value){
    if($city == $value["cityid"]){
        for ($i=0; $i<$length; $i++) {
            if($districts[$i] == $value["id"]){
                $selected = "selected='selected'";
            } else {
                $selected = "";
                //break 2;
            }
            echo "<option ".$selected." value='".$value["id"]."'>".$value["title"]."</option>";
        }
    }
}
```

`Selected="selected"` works fine but the problem is first for each repeated again in for loop, i don't know how can i stop repeating items, just used `break` but no success. Please see whole code in **[ideone](https://ideone.com/Ad9gq1)**, what i have done wrong?

**My goal is to achieve this result in html:**

```html
<select name="Select-District[]" multiple="multiple">
<option selected="selected" value="1">test1</option>
<option selected="selected" value="2">test2</option>
<option value="3">test3</option>
<option value="4">test4</option>
<option value="5">test5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You want to avoid duplicating of items, right? Move curly brace currently bellow echo 'option, etc'...move it above that line, and all should work fine. You are echoing options inside $districts sub-loop...that's the problem...

Comment: @sinisake yes, i tried this before i made this topic, it works but just one of options get `selected`, but i have two.

Comment: @GauravKumar According to this `$districts = explode(",","2,1");` i need to set attribute `selected="selected"` to those option value that equals with `$districts` array. 2 and 1. so the output should select two options. see my answer updated with a snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `in_array` instead of looping it again.

```
foreach ($readJson as $key => $value){
    if($city == $value["cityid"]){
        if(in_array($value["id"], $districts)){
            $selected = "selected='selected'";
        } else {
            $selected = "";
        }
        echo "<option ".$selected." value='".$value["id"]."'>".$value["title"]."</option>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code and i guess its working.

```
<?php

    $readJson = array(
        0 => array(
            'id' => 1,
            'title' => 'test1',
            'cityid' => 1
        ),
        1 => array(
            'id' => 2,
            'title' => 'test2',
            'cityid' => 1
        ),
        2 => array(
            'id' => 3,
            'title' => 'test3',
            'cityid' => 1
        ),
        3 => array(
            'id' => 4,
            'title' => 'test4',
            'cityid' => 1
        ),
        4 => array(
            'id' => 5,
            'title' => 'test5',
            'cityid' => 1
        )
    );

    $city = 1;
    $districts = explode(',' , '2,1');
    $length = sizeof($districts);

    echo "<select name='Select-District[]' multiple='multiple'>";

    $printed = array();

    foreach ($readJson as $key => $value)
    {
        if($city == $value["cityid"])
        {
            if(in_array($value["id"], $districts))
                $selected = "selected='selected'";
            else 
                $selected = "";

            echo "<option ".$selected." value='".$value["id"]."'>".$value["title"]."</option>";          
        }
    }
    echo "</select>";

?>
```

Hope it works.